# Dynamically change the shape of bokeh Figure

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I am building a web app that will display images as part of a data analysis pipeline. For this, I need to dynamically change the width and height of a `Figure` object in bokeh.

With the following code, the shape of the `Figure` is changed, but the change only takes effect after I resize my browser window, even if the browser window resize is ever so small.

```
import bokeh.plotting
import bokeh.models
import bokeh.layouts

# set up the interface
fig1 = bokeh.plotting.figure()
button = bokeh.models.Button(label='scramble')

# define a callback and connect it
def callback():
    fig1.width = int(fig1.width * .8)
button.on_click(callback)

# add everything to the document
bokeh.plotting.curdoc().add_root(bokeh.layouts.column(button, fig1))
```

Is there some update method which I need to run? I have read about "next tick callbacks" but I don't understand if that is relevant.

The above behavior occurs both with firefox and chromium on my gnome system.

Comment: The above code was executed with 'bokeh serve'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the layout is not getting updated. Although your code changes the figure's property value you have to recompute all values in the Document solver for an actual resize to happen.

Here is the line in BokehJS where the resize hook happens:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/coffee/document.coffee#L92

After resize is called at the document level, resize objects re-render:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokehjs/src/coffee/models/layouts/layout_dom.coffee#L61

The problem is that there's not currently, to the best of my knowledge, an exposed way to re-trigger the document resize event.

However you can do it client side. Here's working code using `CustomJS`:

`test.py`

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure


fig = figure()
button = Button(label='scramble')
button.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(fig=fig), code="""
    var old_width = fig.width;
    var doc = fig.document;
    fig.width = old_width * 0.8;
    doc.resize();
""")

col = column(button, fig)
show(col)
```

This can be run with `python test.py`.

Note you could also do this with bokeh server replacing the last line `show(col)` with `curdoc().add_root(col)`, but I didn't do that to emphasize that this is a client-side solution.

Comment: Does this still work in Bokeh Version 1.0.4?  It doesn't appear so.  This is the error message in the browser javascript console:  Uncaught TypeError: doc.resize is not a function
    at t.eval (eval at get (customjs.js:37), <anonymous>:7:9)
    at t.execute (customjs.js:43)
    at e.t.change_input (abstract_button.js:56)
    at e.change_input (button.js:14)
    at e.t._button_click (abstract_button.js:52)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (abstract_button.js:42)

Comment: First thing. Next release is coming out very very soon with wildly improved layout. This is very old code and I wouldn't expect it to work, but I would expect the new code to be much cleaner. The property now would be plot_width (https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/plots.html#bokeh.models.plots.Plot.plot_width). You shouldn't need to do any triggering. Check out this awesome example for some inspiration: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/sizing_mode.py

Comment: Also, now bokeh is passed 1.0, API is promised not to break any more. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to dynamically resize bokeh charts with built in functionality. For example,

`fig = plotting.figure(width=1200, height=900, title="Dynamic plot".format(chartType), sizing_mode='scale_width')`

The key option being `sizing_mode='scale_width'`

The `width` and `height` commands serve as initial values. There are other options for `sizing_mode` so I would look into that.

Comment: I looked into the sizing modes but the described behavior persisted.